# Proof that $\inf A = -\sup(-A)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of real numbers which is bounded below. Let $-A$ be the set of of all numbers $-x$, where $x$ is in $A$. Prove that $\inf A = -\sup(-A)$

So far this is what I have

Let $\alpha=\inf(A)$, which allows us to say that $\alpha \leq x$ for all $x \in A$. Therefore, we know that $-\alpha \geq -x$ for all $x \in -A$. Therefore we know that $-\alpha$ is an upper bound of $-A$. $\ \ \ \ $

Now let $b$ be the upper bound of $-A$. There exists $b \geq-x \implies-b \leq x$ for all $x \in A$. Hence,
\begin{align}
-b & \leq \alpha\\
-\alpha & \leq b\\
-\alpha & = - \inf(A) = \sup (-A)
\end{align}

By multiplying $-1$ on both sides, we get that $\inf(A) = -\sup (-A)$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: +1. For showing your work. People appreciate if you show your work. And your answer is right. Good work!

Comment: how did you get $-b \leq \alpha$?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/947049/589.

Comment: "Therefore, we know that $-\alpha \geq −x$ for all $x \in -A$." Consider $A = \{1, 3, 5\}$ then $\alpha = \mathrm{inf} A = 1$ and $-A = \{-1, -3, -5\}$ and you get a negation to much. With these variables $-1 \geq −x$ for all $x \in \{-1, -3, -5\}$ is not true.

Answer (score 12):

Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of real numbers which is bounded below. Let $−A$ be the set of of all numbers $−x$, where $x$ is in $A$. Prove that $\inf{A}=−\sup{(-A)}$.

I think that the purpose of this question is to show you why it is not required to include the existence of infimum into the Axiom of Completeness.

Here, i will show the existence of infimum of $A$.

$\forall a\in A, \exists x\in\mathbb{R}\text{ such that } x\leq a \implies -x\geq-a \implies -x \text{ is an upper bound for }-A.$

Here, $x$ is an arbitrary lower bound for $A$.

By axiom of completeness, $\exists y\in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that }y=\sup{(-A)}, \text{i.e. }-a\leq y\leq -x \text{ , }\forall a\in A,$
which implies that $x\leq -y \leq a$.

Here, $-y$ is a lower bound for $A$ and $-y$ is at least any lower bound for $A$, which means that $-y = \inf{A}$.

Hence, $-\sup{(-A)} =\inf{A}$.

Comment: first using the Axiom of Completeness you claim that $\forall a\in A, \exists x\in\mathbb{R}\text{ such that } x\leq a \implies -x\geq-a \implies -x \text{ is an upper bound for }-A.$ I think this $x$ is actually the g.l.b of the set $A$, because as I know is this case  the Axiom of Completeness guarantees the existence of inf $A$ not lower bound of $A$ , but then you say $x$ is an arbitrary lower bound, though with the previous claim it's cannot be any lower bound, can you tell me where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Aside from dropping a $-$ sign in your last line, that's good work. (Also, I'd say "let $b$ be *an* upper bound," instead, but it's clear that's what is meant.)

Answer (score 1):

your method was good but you didn't check it . i try to proof it well  :
( sorry my english is not well because i am not a english person )
$a=\inf(A)$  so  $a\le x$ for all $x\in A$. Therefore, $−a\le −x$ for all $-x\in -A$.

Now let $b$ be the upper bound of $−A$. There exists $b\ge−x$ $−b\le x$ for all $x\in .
A$. Hence,
$−b−a−a\le a\le b=−\inf(A)=\sup(−A)$
By multiplying $−1$ on both sides, we get that $\inf(A)=−\sup(−A)$

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but here is essentially your proof written down in an alternative style, which might be helpful.  (See, e.g., [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html) for more details on this proof style.)$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\inf}[1]{\text{inf}(#1)}
\newcommand{\sup}[1]{\text{sup}(#1)}
$

First, let's make our definitions explicit.  The simplest definitions of $\;\inf{\cdot}\;$ and $\;\sup{\cdot}\;$ I know are
\begin{align}
\tag{0} z \leq \inf{A} \;\equiv\; \langle \forall a : a \in A : z \leq a \rangle
\\
\tag{1} \sup{B} \leq z \;\equiv\; \langle \forall b : b \in B : b \leq z \rangle
\end{align}
for any real $\;z\;$, lower-bounded non-empty $\;A\;$ and upper-bounded non-empty $\;B\;$.

---

Armed with these definitions, let's try to lower-bound both sides, starting with the most complex side, so the right hand side: for any $\;z\;$,

$$\calc
    z \leq -\sup{-A}
\op=\hints{negate both sides and swap them}\hint{-- preparing for the definition of $\;\sup{\cdot}\;$}
    \sup{-A} \leq -z
\op=\hints{definition $\ref{1}$}\hints{-- allowed because $\;-A\;$ is upper-bounded and non-empty,}\hints{because $\;A\;$ is lower-bounded and non-empty}\hint{by the definition of $\;-A\;$}
    \langle \forall b : b \in -A : b \leq -z \rangle
\op=\hint{definition of $\;-A\;$}
    \langle \forall b : -b \in A : b \leq -z \rangle
\op=\hint{substitute $\;a := -b\;$; simplify using arithmetic}
    \langle \forall a : a \in A : z \leq a \rangle
\op=\hints{definition $\ref{0}$}\hint{-- allowed because $\;A\;$ is lower-bounded and non-empty}
    z \leq \inf{A}
\endcalc$$
In other words, $\;-\sup{-A}\;$ and $\;\inf{A}\;$ have the same lower bounds, and therefore they are equal.

---

This proof uses the following principle:
$$
x = y \;\equiv\; \langle \forall z :: z \leq x \;\equiv\; z \leq y \rangle
$$

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong:

$A\subset \mathbb{R}$, and $cA=${$y|y=cx, x \in A$}.

Let $c <0$.

Show that $\sup (cA)= c \inf (A)$.

Then

$cx \le M$ $\iff$ $x \ge M/c$, i.e.

$M$ is an upper bound of $cA$

$ \iff$

$M/c$ is a lower bound of $A$.

1)Let $M= \sup (cA)$, then

$x \ge \sup (cA)/c$, $x \in A$.

Hence $\inf A \ge \sup (cA)$.
(Definition of $\inf A$).

2) Let $M/c =\inf A$, then

$cx \le M = c \inf A$.

Hence $\sup (cA)  \le c \inf A$ .
(Definition of $\sup$)

Finally 1) and 2):

$\sup (cA)=c \inf A$.

($c=-1$  in the original problem)