# How to show $-\sup(-A)=\inf(A)$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\emptyset\neq A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ a bounded set. Consider $-A=\{-a:a\in A\}$. I want to prove that $-\sup(-A)=\inf(A)$.

It is easy to see that $-\inf(A)$ is an upper bound of $-A$, so $\sup(-A)\le -\inf(A)$, then $-\sup(-A)\ge \inf(A)$.

How can we prove that $-\sup(-A)\le \inf(A)$?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you want to say, "Consider $-A = \{-a: a \in A \}$?

Comment: So, you've shown that $-\sup(-A)$  is a lower bound for $A$.  Can you show that this lower bound is "tight"?  That is, try to show that for any $\epsilon$, there is an $a$ such that
$$
-\sup(-A) \leq a < -\sup(-A) + \epsilon
$$

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex). You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: In fact both are equal, see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/392129/11994.

Answer (score 4):

You should work directly from the definitions of $\sup$ and $\inf$. That is, prove that if $x = \inf(A)$ then $-x \ge b$ for all $b \in {-A}$ (i.e. $-x$ is an upper bound for $-A$) and that if $y \ge b$ for all $b \in {-A}$ then $y \ge {-x}$ (that is, $-x$ is a *least* upper bound). This verifies that $-x$ is the sup of $-A$, and its proof uses the (similar) definition of $\inf(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

The map $x \mapsto -x$ is an order-inverting bijection $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

It sends lower bounds for $A$ to upper bounds for $-A$, and vice-versa, hence the result.

Comment: Or, you could call it an order-preserving map $(\mathbb{R},<)\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},>)$ - i.e. going from the order to its dual

Answer (score 1):

You can round out the argument by using a nice symmetry. In particular, you already have that:
$$-\sup(-A)\geq \inf(A)$$
and easily, by the same reasoning, that
$$-\inf(-B)\leq \sup(B)$$
Now, if we set $A=-B$, then we get, from the first inequality, that:
$$-\sup(B)\geq \inf(-B)$$
then negating both sides:
$$\sup(B)\leq -\inf(-B)$$
but we can simply tack on the second inequality
$$\sup(B)\leq -\inf(-B)\leq \sup(B)$$
which implies $-\inf(-B)=\sup(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

My approach starts out similar to @CliveNewstead's but then I let $-\gamma = \sup(-A)$ and used the fact that the infimum is unique.

Since $A$ is nonempty and bounded below, $A = \{a:a\in A\}$ and $\inf(A) = \alpha$. Now, $-A = \{-a:a\in A\}$ is also nonempty. Since $\alpha$ is the infimum of $A$, $\alpha\leq a$ for all $a\in A$. By multiplying by $-1$, we get the following inequality
  $$                                                                            
  -\alpha\geq -a.                                       
  $$
That is, $-\alpha$ is an upper bound of $-A$. Suppose $-\gamma = \sup(-A)$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $-\gamma + \varepsilon\not\in -A$
  $$                                                                            
  -\alpha\geq -\gamma + \varepsilon\geq -\gamma\geq -a                          
  $$
Again, by multiplying by negative one, we have
  $$                                                                            
  \alpha\leq \gamma - \varepsilon\leq\gamma\leq a                              
  $$
but $\gamma - \varepsilon\notin A$ so $\gamma$ is a lower bound of $A$ which would contradict the fact that $\alpha$ is the greatest lower bound of $A$. In order for $\gamma$ to be the lower bound, $\gamma = \alpha$ since the infimum is unique. So $-\alpha$ is the supremum of $-A$. Therefore, $\alpha = \inf(A) = -\sup(-A) = -(-\alpha) = \alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Basiclly by using the definition of supremum and infimum we can easily see that:
$$
\sup(A) \Longleftrightarrow \exists c_0 = \min\{c|\forall a \in A: a \le c\}
$$
$$
\sup(-A) \Longleftrightarrow \exists c_1 = \min\{c|\forall \bar a \in -A: \bar a \le c\} = \min\{c|\forall a \in A: -a \le c\}
$$
$$
-\sup(-A) \Longleftrightarrow \exists c_2 = \max\{c|\forall a \in A: a \ge c\} = \inf(A)
$$