# If $c \in \mathbb{R}, c<0, A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ prove that $\sup(cA) = c \cdot \inf(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

This is what I have done, but I am not sure if it is correct.

$s = \sup(cA) \Rightarrow s \ge -ca, \, \forall a \in A$ and $\nexists t \in \mathbb{R} : t \ge -ca, t < s, \forall a \in A$

Restated with the sign applied to the inequality:

$\dfrac{s}{c}\le a, \forall a \in A$ and $\nexists t \in \mathbb{R} : \dfrac{t}{c}\le a, \forall a \in A, t < s \Rightarrow \dfrac{s}{c} = \inf(A)$

$\dfrac{s}{c} = \inf(A) \Rightarrow s = \sup(cA) = c \cdot \inf(A)$

Is this correct?

Comment: Note that if $s = sup(cA)$ then $s \ge ca$ for all $a \in A$

Comment: Hint: $sup(A) =  - inf(-A)$, where $-A = \{-a : a \in A \}$

Comment: @Vader: thanks, but is the proof above valid?

Comment: I don't think so. If $s>ca,\ \forall a \in A$ then it is not true that $s>-ca,\ \forall a \in A$

Comment: These post might be useful in relation to your problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488022/how-to-prove-infs-sup-s and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947035/how-to-show-sup-a-infa (If you know this, you can reduce the problem to the case $c>0$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt at a proof is, at the least, insufficient. I suggest you to use less symbols and to spell out what you need to prove.

---

Let $r=\inf(A)$; you want to prove

1. $cr\ge x$, for all $x\in cA$
2. for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $y\in cA$ such that $y>cr-\varepsilon$.

First condition. Since $r=\inf(A)$, we know that $r\le a$, for all $a\in A$; if $x\in cA$, then $x=ca$, for some $a\in A$; from $r\le a$ and $c<0$, it follows $cr\ge ca=x$.

Second condition. There exists $b\in A$ such that $r-\dfrac{\varepsilon}{c}>b$, because $-\varepsilon/c>0$. Then
$$
c\left(r-\frac{\varepsilon}{c}\right)<cb
$$
which is the same as
$$
cr-\varepsilon < cb
$$
and we can take $y=cb\in cA$.