# Why is $\limsup \int_E f_n = -\liminf \left(-\int_E f_n \right) $?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Why is $\limsup \int_E f_n = -\liminf \left(-\int_E f_n \right) $?

Could anyone give me a detailed proof of this?

I know that **lim sup** is the largest accumulation accumulation points of a sequence and **lim inf** is the smallest accumulation points of a sequence, but then what? how can I use this in proving the above statement?

Comment: write explicitly the definitions of limit superior and limit inferior and you are almost done. By last note that if $A\subset\Bbb R$ then $\sup A=-\inf(-A)$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392129/proof-that-inf-a-sup-a

Comment: but here we are dealing with functions and not sets @Masacroso

Comment: but here we are dealing with functions and not sets @CalvinKhor , so why there is an equality? is not it should be inequality?

Comment: @Smart note that $$\limsup\int_E f_n:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}\int_E f_k$$ and $$\sup_{k\ge n}\int_E f_k:=\sup\left\{\int_E f_k:k\ge n\right\}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with integration, it's a basic fact about sequences of real numbers. For $A\subset\Bbb R$ write $$-A=\{-a:a\in A\}.$$

> > **Trivial Exercise.** $\alpha$ is an upper bound for $A$ is an only if $-\alpha$ is a lower bound for $-A$.

Now, since $\sup$ is simply the least upper bound and  $\inf$ is the greatest lower bound,

> > **Easy Exercise.** $\sup A=-\inf-A$.

And then using the definitions and the Easy  Exercise:

> > **Exercise.** If $(a_n)$ is any sequence of reals then $\limsup a_n=-\liminf -a_n$.

Proof:
 $$\begin{align}-\liminf-a_n&=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf_{j>n}-a_k=-\lim_n-\sup_{k>n}a_k=\lim_n\sup_{k>n}a_k=\limsup a_n.\end{align}$$

(In case the relevance of all this is  not clear: Let $a_n=\int_Ef_n$.)

Comment: More generally, if $f$ is an increasing function, then $\sup f(A) \le f(\sup A)$ and if $f$ is decreasing then $\sup f(A) \le f (\inf A)$. These are equalities if $f$ is continuous at $\sup A$ or $\inf A$ respectively.

Comment: Does the question in the title includes supremum over sets or functions?

Comment: @Secretly Strictly speaking the answer is neither - the question asks about the sup and inf of _sequences_. If I have to say sets or functions, I'd say sets, because if $a_n$ is a sequence of reals and $A$ is the set $\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ then $\sup_na_n=\sup A$.

Comment: @Secretly But to answer what you're probably really asking, no,  the question has nothing whatever to do with the fact that $f_n$ is a function; the question is just about the _sequence_ $a_n$, where it just happens that $a_n=\int_Ef_n$.