# Verification of proof that $\sup(A) = - \inf(-A)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Given $A \neq \emptyset$ and bounded above define $-A:= \{-x: x \in A\}$

I am trying to prove that $\sup(A) = - \inf(-A)$ I have prove already that the $\inf(A) = - \sup(-A)$.

Proof attempt:
Since $A$ is non-empty and bounded above, there exists $\alpha = \sup(A)$. Therefore, for all $x \in A, \alpha \geq x$. if $x \in A$ and $x < \alpha$ then $x$ is not an upper bound for $A$.

I claim that $- \alpha = \inf(-A)$.

Let $y \in -A$ then there exists $x \in A$ such that $-x = y$. Then $\alpha \geq x, -\alpha \leq -x = y$. Thus $y \geq - \alpha$ for all $y \in -A$. Therefore $-\alpha$ is a lower bound for $-A$.

We need to show that any real number >− is not a lower bound of −.

Since >−, −< and thus − is not an upper bound of  (by definition of =sup()). Thus there is ∈ so that −<. So >− and thus  is not a lower bound of −.

The result follows.

Comment: The supremum of a set does not need to be an element of the set, so you are not justified in saying "since $\alpha \in A$", nor do you need that for the proof.

Comment: The duplicate is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392129/proof-that-inf-a-sup-a?rq=1)

Comment: Please, don't edit the post after receiving the answer.... now you make me looks like an idiot pointing out the mistake that you didn't make....

Comment: Apologies. I believe the result is correct now and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several mistakes: (1) the supremum $\alpha$ might not be in $A$: think of $A =  (0,1)$. (2) You need to show that any real number $y >-\alpha$ is not a lower bound of $-A$. But instead you assumed $y\in -A$.

The correct argument is that, since $y >-\alpha$, $-y < \alpha$ and thus $-y$ is not an upper bound of $A$ (by definition of $\alpha = \sup (A)$). Thus there is $x\in A$ so that $-y <x$. So $y>-x$ and thus $y$ is not a lower bound of $-A$.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my post to include what you have said. But don't I still need to have $y \in -A$ to show that $- \alpha$ is a lower bound for $-A$?

Comment: Yes, there's no mistake there. @learningmathematics